# Web app to send Bulk SMS

Tags: webapp-rec, sms

Any recommendations for web apps for sending bulk **SMS** to several mobile numbers?

Comment: [ClickATell](http://www.clickatell.com/) seems to support bulk messages easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clickatell and Commzgate support bulk messages - both have easy-to-use web APIs as well. Both these services are quite expensive though. 
If most of the SMSes you are sending are local, you can setup an SMS gateway (ozeki, visualtron etc), a GSM modem and send SMSes using a purchased SIM card. Remember to test using a prepaid SIM to avoid running up a large phone bill in case the automated system malfunctions.

Comment: The SMS gateways you mentioned look really interesting.  I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: Yep, if I am not mistaken, Clickatell gives you a few free credits when you sign up to test the API. (though the message includes some text indicating its a free trial by Clickatell)

Comment: I've been using ClickaTell for a while now (over an year) and I'm satisfied with their service and support.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [TextAnywhere](http://ws.textanywhere.net/web/home/default.aspx) for years. (This is a UK service I think)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the provider, you can use the [SMS Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) -- email addresses. You can find a list of them on an [wikipedia's page history](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=SMS_gateway&oldid=284001686). This is also totally free for the sender.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [smstools3](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/). I've set one on a little [excito bubba server](http://www.excito.com/) using a HUAWEI usb key to send and receive SMS messages. It worked very well. If you have a lot of in/out sms messages clickatell is the way to go otherwise setting smstools3 will very easy and fun.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check [2-WaySMS](https://www.2-waysms.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Commzgate also has an free SMS gateway server that you can download and send SMS with GSM modems

http://www.commzgate.com/commzgate/messagingserver.php

http://www.commzgate.com/commzgate/download.php